# Error in accessing file in S3-Bucket using Django

Tags: django

I am using `Django-mailbox`, `AWS-EC2` instance and `AWS-S3` , So I am trying to send an attachment with mail and receive it on S3 bucket and I am successful to achieve this.

Next while accessing that attachment file from saved path, it showing me following error, however file is saved successfully in given path, you can see in folder dir.

[image]

My folder structure is as follows

[image]

Let me know if any further details needed.

Comment: The paths don't seem to match -- I don't see "/14/change" in the folder structure below.